# What is the difference between photons from an electron and photons from a proton?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

So, I am trying to get my head 'round the workings of electromagnetism.

Pretend I am 5 years old.

Protons send out photons to electrons that cause the electrons to accelerate towards the proton, and vice versa. Is that correct?

When those same photons from protons are received by protons though, the recipient protons move away.

What's the difference between the 'proton-photons' and the 'electron-photons' fundamentally?

Comment: *I am trying to get my head 'round the workings of electromagnetism.* For an initial understanding of EM, it is much easier to understand it *classically* rather than using quantum field theory.

Comment: If you are trying to understand *quantum electrodynamics*, then your question is a good one (although almost certainly a duplicate).

Comment: @G.Smith Yes I think I am trying to understand the latter. I am actually interested in understanding why it doesn't seem to be currently possible to just *emit* the right flavour of photon to repel or attract matter at will, by emulating whatever it is that different particles do to photons when they emit them

Comment: It’s been awhile since I took QED, but as far as I know there aren’t different kinds of virtual photons. And you shouldn't think of virtual photons as particles at all.

Answer (score 2):

The description of EM in terms of (virtual) photons is very good for describing/predicting scattering cross sections and decay rates, which is what particle physics deals with most of the time.

It is not very good at describing attraction and repulsion - which is the first thing people think about forces in everyday life.

So for something like Rutherford scattering the first order cross sections for electron-proton scattering and positron-proton scattering, involving interchange of one virtual photon, are exactly the same. There is a factor $Q_1 Q_2$ in the amplitude which is $+1$ for $e^+p$ and $-1$ for $e^-p$, but this is squared to get the probabilty.

[image: Feynman diagrams for 1- and 2-photon exchange]

If you go to second order, exchanging two photons, the factor in the amplitude is  $(Q_1 Q_2)^2$, even less promising. But the interference term between the two amplitudes is now $Q_1^3 Q_2^3$ so this does produce a difference between the two charges.

Extending this to many orders, such differences produce the attraction/repulsion result which is the main feature of everyday electrostatics.

So: the virtual photons from positive and negative charges are the same. But the way in which they interfere with other virtual photons involved in other exchanges produces, eventually, an attraction/repulsion difference.

Comment: It'll take me some time to digest that. What's a first/second/third order cross section?

Comment: I've added a picture of 1st and 2nd order diagrams which I hope will help

Comment: Ok I guess I need to do some basic reading. I don't even know what a virtual photon is.